# Download part of file from FTP server using `FTPClient`

Tags: java, ftp, download

Is it possible to download only a part of a file from my FTP server using [FTPClient](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html)? This part should by specified by two `long` values `m` and `n` meaning "starting from byte `m` untill byte `n`.

Is such a thing actually possible using the FTP protocol?

Comment: It is in fact possible with the FTP protocol: http://serverfault.com/questions/18834/how-to-ftp-get-a-partial-file-only As to your specific library, I am unsure.

Comment: Do you know a java FTP library which supports it?

Answer (score 1):

Using the [ftp4j library](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/ftp4j/) you can do the following:

```
client.download("remoteFile.ext", new java.io.File("localFile.ext"), 1056);
```

The documentation describes this method as the following:

> This one resumes the download operation starting from the 1056th byte of the file. The first byte transferred will be the 1057th.